# jersey 2 bean validation Don't work

Tags: java, validation, jersey-2.0

I now use is jersey2.13 and spring4.X, and can't get jersey bean validation to work.

The following is my configuration and code snippets:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <!-- jersey ServletContainer -->
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- jersey  resource packages-->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json,
                com.ghca.easyview.server.api.resource
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- jersey  provider classnames-->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyApiDeclarationProvider,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyResourceListingProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ghca.easyview.server.api.context.JerseyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!--  jersey beanValidation  -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/se/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- jersey swagger UI -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://10.143.132.99:4000/api/se/rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ghca.easyview.server.api.plugin.swagger.Bootstrap2</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

JerseyApplication.java:

package com.ghca.easyview.server.api.context;

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;

import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory;
/**
 * ContactCard application configuration
 * JAX-RS application
 */
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig{

    public JerseyApplication(){
        property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.BV_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
        // Resource Package Address 
        packages("com.ghca.easyview.server.api.resource");
        //Validation.
        register(ValidationConfigurationContextResolver.class);

    }
    /**
     */
    public static class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig>{
        @Context
        private ResourceContext resourceContext;
        @Override
        public ValidationConfig getContext(final Class<?> type) {
            return new ValidationConfig().constraintValidatorFactory(resourceContext.getResource(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.class));
        }
    }
}
```

PersonResource.java:

```
package com.ghca.easyview.server.api.resource;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ghca.easyview.server.api.request.validation.model.Person;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;

@Component
@Path("/person")
@Api(value = "/person", description = "person", position = 1)
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
public class PersonResource {

    @POST
    public Response create(@Valid @NotNull Person person) {
        System.out.println(person);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Person.java:

```
package com.ghca.easyview.server.api.request.validation.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

public class Person {
    @NotNull
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 2, max = 20)
    private String name;
    @Email(message = "{contact.wrong.email}", regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}")
    private String email;
    @Pattern(message = "{contact.wrong.phone}", regexp = "[0-9]{3,9}")
    private String phone;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email
                + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are disabling everything, but after testing, removing the disable properties makes it work

```
//property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
//property(ServerProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
//property(ServerProperties.BV_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
```

Those properties are false by default, which allows auto-discovery. You are disabling it.

Comment: hi,peeskillet,Or not? I put it comments

Comment: Hmmm, Works fine for me. Do you actually have the [jersey-bean-validation dependency](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13254)?

Comment: Yeah I dunno. Besides all your swagger stuff I pretty much have the same configuration you have, copy and pasted all your classes. When I keep the properties it doesn't work. When I remove them, it works, I get the validation output. That's about all I can tell you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76852/discussion-between-jack-and-peeskillet).

Comment: hi,peeskillet ,i reputation Can't chat? U has email?

Comment: You should have enough rep now :-)

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.
Not yet? Refresh the page